# Objective C truncate double value to 2 decimal places

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to truncate a double value to two decimal places. I tried using:

```
[highScoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Highscore: %.2f",finalTime]];
```

but I found that it rounds the number after 2 places. This makes the score I'm reporting to game center and the score displayed in app different. How can I cut off the rest of the decimal without rounding it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@dasdom answer is great. But if you do not like implicit casting you can use

```
finalTime = trunc(finalTime * 100) / 100;
```

If you will receive an error that 'trunc' function is unknown - just import math.h header:

```
#import <math.h>
```

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using, so I accepted this one. Thanks @dasdom as well!

Comment: Also, this makes "%f" the correct variable to use. Upvoted because this solved all my rounding issues.

Answer (score 2):

Dump solution (not tested):

```
finalTime = ((int)(finalTime * 100.0f))/100.0f;
```